# Error: undefined reference to 'player()'

Tags: c++, reference, header, syntax-error, undefined

fellow programmers! I'm looking to get into game development, so I'm trying to write my own, very simple text battle simulator. You get to choose a player name and fight with monsters of your choice. Anyway, I'm aiming to write simple code at first, then expand and add more classes as I go. Here are my two only files for now:

**player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <string>
using std::string;


class player
{
public:
player();

const int maxHealth = 100;
int armorModifier = 0;
int playerLevel = 1;
int gold = 0;
int currentHealth = maxHealth;

string Name;

~player();
};
#endif // PLAYER_H
```

**BattlesMain.cpp**

```
/* GAME FEATURES THAT ARE COMMENTED WILL BE IMPLEMENTED AT A LATER TIME */


#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
  /* MAIN MENU */

cout << "Monster Battles: Text Action, v0.1\n";
cout << "Welcome, fighter!\n";
cout << "1.New Game\n";
// cout << "2.Load Game\n";
cout << "3.Quit Game\n";

char choice;

cin >> choice;

/* GAME LOOP */

while (choice !='4')
{
   if (choice == '1')
   {
       player Player1;

       cout << "Arena Host: Hello, fighter. What is your name?\n";
       cin >> Player1.Name;
       cout << "Welcome to the arena, " << Player1.Name << ". Here, you will \n";
       cout << "be given the chance to battle fearsome monsters for fortune and \n";
       cout << "fame. With the gold you win, you can visit our shop to buy new weapons, \n";
       cout << "armor and other useful items. Since you are unarmed, here's a THIEF'S DAGGER. \n";
       cout << "It's not much, but you'll hopefully be able to buy better items later! Good luck!\n";


}

return 0;}
```

Notice that this is my first attempt at creating even a small project, so bear with me for any bad coding style (feedback is more than welcome). This is a stripped down version of what I want to do, as I also state in the comments. The thing is, when I try to execute the file, wherever I use Player1.Name, I get an error 'Error: undefined reference to 'player()'. I'm currently using Code::Blocks for Windows 7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a *definition* for your constructor and your destructor (you only have a *declaration* in the definition of the `player` class).

If the constructor and destructor are not supposed to do anything, just do not declare them explicitly. The compiler will implicitly generate them for you.

In particular, a user-provided destructor has the (most likely undesired, I would say) consequence of inhibiting the implicit generation of a move constructor and move-assignment operator (whereasthe implicit generation of a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator is only deprecated in C++11).

Also, the way you initialize variables is allowed only since C++11. In case you are curious how member variables would be initialized in C++03, that would be done using  a [constructor's initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
player::player()
    :
    maxHealth(100),
    armorModifier(0),
    playerLevel(),
    gold(0),
    currentHealth(maxHealth)
{
}
```

Of course, you would have to omit the initializers in the class definition, and you would still have to include a declaration for the constructor.

Comment: and the assignment of values to the member variables in the class declaration is also not allowed

Comment: Thank you, Andy! That did the job; my program ran as expected. 

Wojo: why is that? What if I want to initialize values (like the constant max health of my player)? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @DimitrisAlmeidaKokkaliaroglo: Yes, there are other ways of doing it (for instance in a constructor's initialization list). However, in C++11 what you are doing is allowed

Comment: That's useful to know. Show, in the old standard, how would I initialize my variables in the constructor? I'd like to know for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @DimitrisAlmeidaKokkaliaroglo: I edited the answer to show that. If this post answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted :)